# Is there a way to make AngularJS work with HTML-first?

Tags: angularjs, seo

Is there a way to have a HTML-view with pre-populated values from the server, and then get AngularJS to read those values into it's `$scope`?

I'm thinking of a scenario where the HTML is like this:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <div ng-bind="title">Test Title</div>
    <div ng-bind="itemCount">33</div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        <div ng-bind="item.title">Item 1 Title</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button ng-click="update()">Update</button>
```

And the JavaScript is like this:

```
function TestController($scope) {
    $scope.update = function() {
        console.log($scope.title); // Should log "Test Title"
    };
}
```

The thought behind this is to let the **server render** HTML that **search engines can index**, but have a **JavaScript-model-representation of the content** for manipulation through JS.

Answer (score 7):

While `ng-init` is one solution, it requires you to explicitly set the value. So here is an alternative solution.

http://plnkr.co/edit/pq8yR9zVOHFI6IRU3Pvn?p=preview

**Note** : This solution wont work for `ng-repeat`. Control flow directives cant be used with this. But for simple extraction of information from `ng-bind` this works pretty well. All that you need to do is add the `default` directive ( code in plunk ) to wherever you are doing the bind and it will extract the text content and push it to the scope variable.

**EDIT (solution with ng-repeat):**

So, I was thinking of a way to make ng-repeat also work the same way. But getting ng-repeat to work like this isnt an easy job ( see the code for proof :P ). I have finally found a solution -  here you go :

http://plnkr.co/edit/GEWhCNVMeNVaq9JA2Xm2?p=preview

There are a couple of things you need to know before you use this. This hasnt been thoroughly tested. It only works for repeating over arrays ( not objects ). There could be cases that have not been covered. I am overriding ngRepeat itself which could have other consequences. When you loop through the items ( in your server side code ) dont forget to add `default="true"` on the first element and `default` on the rest of the elements.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps a lot, thanks. Do you have any tips on how to manage the `repeat`-situation?

Comment: I dont currently have a solution for situations with `ng-repeat` - Will let you know if I find one.

Comment: @SebNilsson : I have updated the answer to include another plunk that supports `ng-repeat` as well. Have a look.

Comment: That all seems nice and (almost) dandy, but there're many others that may be much more complex. `ngIf` where content isn't part of HTML or `ngInclude`... There should be a better way... What if we also delivered model as JSON along in the view? So angular should only initialize on that  instead of parsing HTML. This could theoretically make it work for all, right?

Answer (score 0):

Add  `ng-init` to your elements with the value so that it will work the way you want.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInit

Comment: Will that work for collections? And how do I keep my view synced with model-updates?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is to make your application searchable by serving static files in parallell. Read more about it here http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html

Comment: "If you use Apache..." - I'm not. Also, hash-bangs kills baby-kittens.